# When/where to initialize client with twitter gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am new to ruby on rails and am trying to write a simple application that features oauth login and interfaces with the Twitter API via sferik's twitter gem. The documentation suggests configuring the client as follows:

```
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
config.consumer_key        = Rails.application.config.twitter_key
config.consumer_secret     = Rails.application.config.twitter_secret
config.access_token        = Rails.application.config.omniauth_token
config.access_token_secret = Rails.application.config.omniauth_secret
```

My question is where in my project should I have this and is it normal to have this block repeated across multiple files/methods? Right now I only have a user model and a home_controller and a sessions_controller.

Please let me know if I should change anything about this question or its phrasing as this is my first StackOverflow question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Initiate the 'client' immediately before the time it is required.

You will need to change the access_key and access_token to match the Twitter account you plan on accessing.

If you intend on using the same Twitter account throughout your application, you could create a global 'client' variable in an initializer (config/initializers/twitter.rb).